# Tricky ellipse problem

Tags: numerics

I have this equation and I need to show it is en equation of ellipse, could anyone help me?

```
5x^2 - 4xy + 5y^2 = 21
```

Comment: Tomas, your question does not read as a problem with the *Mathematica* software package, but rather a math one (in which case it would be more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Only way you can verify this on Mathematica is doing it visually, ContourPlot[5 x^2 - 4 x y + 5 y^2 == 21, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

Comment: See: [Ellipse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html)

Answer (score 5):

What you want is not very clear. On the one hand it is easy to visualize the region:

```
RegionPlot[5 x^2 - 4 x*y + 5 y^2 <= 21, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

On the other hand, one can bring the expression to its canonical form. Its left-hand part is:

```
 expr1 = 5 x^2 - 4 x*y + 5 y^2;
```

Let us make a replacement: `x -> z + a*t, y -> z - b*t`:

```
expr2 = Collect[(expr1 /. {x -> z + a*t, y -> z - b*t} // Expand), {t, z, z*t}]

(*   (5 a^2 + 4 a b + 5 b^2) t^2 + (6 a - 6 b) t z + 6 z^2  *)
```

And now choose `a` equal to `b`:

```
expr3 = expr2 /. {a -> 1/Sqrt[14], b -> 1/Sqrt[14]}

(*  t^2 + 6 z^2  *)
```

Have fun!